# Semantic UI React Sidebar Pushable

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to create a left sidebar only for desktop (min width 1200px), in other case (tablet, mobile), needs to hide the sidebar. I'm using [Sidebar Pushable from Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/#types-sidebar).

I tried this demo to this but doesn't works:

```js
              <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
                        <Sidebar
                            as={Menu}
                            animation='push'
                            icon='labeled'
                            inverted
                            vertical
                            visible={window.innerWidth >= 1200 ? true : false}
                            width='thin'
                        >
                            <Menu.Item as='a'>
                                <Icon name='home' />
                                Home
                            </Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item as='a'>
                        <Sidebar.Pusher>
                            <Segment basic>
                                 //CONTENT
                                
                            </Segment>
                        </Sidebar.Pusher>
                    </Sidebar.Pushable>
```

Someone else had the same problem? Many Thanks!
Armando

Comment: Does it not work when you resize your window? and once you resize your window and reload the page, it works?

Comment: Hi @cdoshi!, only when I resize the window, no from the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed. After I use a state value, works (instead of window.innerWidth). Maybe was an issue with render loads times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not with render load times. The issue is that react does not re-render a component unless the state of that component changes. Since you had tied the visible prop with window.innerWidth directly, for that component the state was not changing and hence was not re-rendering. Checkthis link with working code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-xqhjl?file=/example.js