# Hiding Sidebar of semantic ui react in desktop or tablet view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

```js
< Sidebar.Pushable as = {    Segment  } >
  <  Sidebar as = {  Menu}
animation = 'overlay'
icon = 'labeled'
inverted
onHide = {
  this.handleSidebarHide
}
vertical
visible = {
  this.state.visible
}
width = 'thin'
className = "sidecolor" >
  <  Menu.Item as = 'a' >
  <  Icon name = 'home' / >
  Home 
  <  /Menu.Item> 
  <Menu.Item as = 'a' >
  <  Icon name = 'gamepad' / >
  Games
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item as = 'a' >
  <  Icon name = 'camera' / >
  Channels
  </Menu.Item>
  <  /Sidebar>

  <  Sidebar.Pusher dimmed = {   this.state.visible  } >
  <  Toolbar show = {  this.handleShowClick}/>
  <div className = "heading"
style = {
    {
      minHeight: "93vh",
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  } >
  {    view  }
  <  div style = {    {      height: "50%"  }  } >
  {    formDialog  }
  < /div>
  <  /div> 
  <  Footer / >
  <  /Sidebar.Pusher>
  <  /Sidebar.Pushable>
```

```html
<div onClick={props.show} className="toggle">
  <Icon name="sidebar" />
</div>
```

I am implementing semantic ui react with my app and I have a problem with the sidebar component.
I have created a toggle button in my toolbar which is only visible in mobile devices. The toggle button triggers the sidebar and you cannot trigger the sidebar from desktop or tablet view. Now when I trigger the sidebar from mobile view and resize my browser to desktop view, the sidebar is still visible. How can I prevent it so that the sidebar is always hidden in desktop or tablet mode.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570499/semantic-ui-react-sidebar-pushable/62869990?noredirect=1#comment111177192_62869990) but there is no answer.

I pass the function to show sidebar into the toolbar and the toggle icon which is only visible in mobile device triggers the sidebar.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried please??

Comment: Please provide some code or codesendbox example. Answering on your question without code is almost impossible

Comment: I have added code you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to hide sideBar for tablet and phone. You can use react semantic responsive tag as per your need.

```
<Sidebar.Pushable as={ Segment }>
  <Responsive as={Segment} minWidth={768}>
    <Sidebar as={ Menu } animation='overlay' icon='labeled' inverted onHide={ 
       this.handleSidebarHide } vertical visible={
      this.state.visible } width='thin' className="sidecolor">
      <Menu.Item as='a'>
        <Icon name='home' />
          </Sidebar.Pusher>
          Home 
      </Menu.Item> 
    </Sidebar> 
  </Responsive>
  <Sidebar.Pusher dimmed={ this.state.visible }>
  </Sidebar.Pusher> 
</Sidebar.Pushable>
```

Comment: This seems to bee working but it is hiding the sidebar only and I cannot seem to be able to hide the backdrop generated by sidebar by the code
dimmed={ this.state.visible }